# The request was rejected because the HTTP method "CONNECT" was not included within the whitelist [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT]

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am getting RequestRejectedException exception when deployed as .war in AWS. But when i deploy it as .jar in Heroku i did get any exception.
Could anyone help me understand why this is happening?

I am not requesting to HTTP "Connet" anywhere in my app.

> 2019-06-21 12:15:40,377 ERROR o.s.b.w.s.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [The request was rejected because the HTTP method "CONNECT" was not included within the whitelist [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT]]
>   org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the HTTP method "CONNECT" was not included within the whitelist [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectForbiddenHttpMethod(StrictHttpFirewall.java:316)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:292)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:194)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
>           at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:685)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.csrf().disable().
    authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**","/scss/**","/vendor/**","/public/**","/**", "/static/**","/admin/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/callbackurl/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll() 
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

}

Comment: Can you add your Security Configuration?

Comment: @TA I have added security config above

Comment: It might form one of the AWS services because I got the same. I was assuming an attack, but it looks common to the AWS hosting.

Comment: I have the same issue - have you figured out the cause???

Answer (score 3):

CONNECT isn't allowed by [default](http://mvpjava.com/spring-boot-security-httpfirewall/) as HTTP method

> If your try sending a TRACE or CONNECT, then that would be considered  a forbidden HTTP method and therefore a RequestRejectedException would get thrown with message “The request was rejected because the HTTP method  was not included within the whitelist“.

Try adding it using [setAllowedHttpMethods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/firewall/StrictHttpFirewall.html#setAllowedHttpMethods-java.util.Collection-)

> You can override this behavior by specifying your own white list via method `setAllowedHttpMethods`. It is also possible to turn this off and allow any HTTP method by calling `setUnsafeAllowAnyHttpMethod(boolean)` however this will open you up to HTTP verb tampering and XST attacks.

Comment: @Mesh1889 But this is the (cause of) error in question

Comment: yes it is, but i am not able to understand how "CONNET" is getting called even thought i didn't make any CONNET request. This is only happening when i deploy app as .war